# Copy sheet to new workbook with cell data as title

Tags: excel, vba

I have used the below and want to modify it to not overwrite the file but create a new file how do I do that or can I modify the new file string to include a cell value in the file name + Daily Report cell value is = to yesterdays day and is formatted like 3-Mar-2022 so in the end I would want every new file to be yesterdays date + Daily Report

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim newWb As Workbook
    Dim newWbPath As String: newWbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Daily Report.xlsx"
    Set newWb = Workbooks.Add

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily Reports").Cells.Copy
    newWb.Worksheets(1).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    newWb.SaveAs newWbPath
    newWb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: As a side note, whenever you're copying just values, you can save a lot of time by directly assigning the values and not using the clipboard. `Range1.Value = Range2.Value` can copy all the values in a single line.

Comment: I'm not understanding the question. You have the line `newWbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Daily Report.xlsx"`. If you want the file to be called something else, just change this line. If you want it to change automatically everyday you can add the current day with `Date` like `... & "\Daily Report " & Date &".xlsx"`. Or if you want a cell value in there, do the same thing but instead of `Date` just put `Cell(row,column).Value`

Comment: Yesterday would be `Date - 1`.

Comment: Okay sorry for being confusing So my data in cell A1 contains the date and want A1 to be part of the filename. Doing this should create a unique file every time and will not over write the existing one. So I think that is all I need modified but not sure what needs to change to accomplish that. So this is what I would want it to look like Dim newWbPath As String: newWbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\(A1)&Daily Report.xlsx" and my file name would be 3-4-2022 Daily Report.xlsx instead of just Daily Report.xlxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Export a Worksheet to a New Workbook

**Copy Values Only**

```vb
Sub ExportDailyReport()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Daily Reports"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "" ' if you don't want it to be e.g. 'Sheet1'
    ' I prefer " yyyymmdd hhmmss" (stays sorted in WinExp) and after the name.
    Const dDatePattern As String = "m-d-yyyy"
    Const dDateNameSeparator As String = " "
    Const dNameRight As String = "Daily Report.xlsx"
    ' Both
    Const DateCellAddress As String = "A1"
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.UsedRange
    
    ' Destination
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' single ws
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
    If Len(dName) > 0 Then dws.Name = dName ' rename worksheet, or not
    
    ' Reference the destination range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range(srg.Cells(1).Address) _
        .Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
    
    ' Copy values by assignment (most efficient).
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    
    ' Build the destination file path.
    Dim dFilePath As String: dFilePath = swb.Path & "\" _
        & Format(dws.Range(DateCellAddress).Value, dDatePattern) _
        & dDateNameSeparator & dNameRight
    
    ' Save and close.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
    dwb.SaveAs dFilePath
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    ' Inform.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Daily report exported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Copy As-Is**

```vb
Sub ExportDailyReportAsIs()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Daily Reports"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "" ' if you don't want it to be 'Daily Reports'
    ' I prefer " yyyymmdd hhmmss" (stays sorted in WinExp) and after the name.
    Const dDatePattern As String = "m-d-yyyy"
    Const dDateNameSeparator As String = " "
    Const dNameRight As String = "Daily Report.xlsx"
    ' Both
    Const DateCellAddress As String = "A1"
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Return the copy of the worksheet in a new workbook.
    sws.Copy
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
    If Len(dName) > 0 Then dws.Name = dName ' rename worksheet, or not
    ' To remove the formulas you can do:
    'dws.UsedRange.Value = dws.UsedRange.Value
    
    ' Build the destination file path.
    Dim dFilePath As String: dFilePath = swb.Path & "\" _
        & Format(dws.Range(DateCellAddress).Value, dDatePattern) _
        & dDateNameSeparator & dNameRight
    
    ' Save and close.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
    dwb.SaveAs dFilePath
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    ' Inform.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Daily report exported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: I tired this Copy As-IS and getting Runtime error '9' subscript out of range

Comment: The code needs to be in the workbook with the worksheet that you are copying that is worksheet "Daily Reports".

Comment: LOL im an idiot tryiong to learn new things, got it figured out. I had changed the sheet name so updated the VBA to reflect that. By an off chance do you know how to automate this to where when this opens it waits for data refresh to complete then do the copy and save?

Comment: One other thing is how would I just copy the entire workbook vs the 1 sheet and keep everything else the same essentially just change the workbook name to the above. I really do appreciate the help you have provided

Comment: Maybe look into `SaveCopyAs`.

Comment: I ended up creating a power shell script to open the file refresh and wait for finish then run the above macro. Then created a scheduled task to run the script at 7:00am Daily @VBasic2008 thank you so much for the assistance with the macro.